# datetime('now') gives wrong time

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

The System-Time of my Android emulator is correct (currently 13:42). But when i use the `datetime('now')`-function to set the current time in my SQLite Database, the returned value is wrong (11:42).

Is there another time i need to set to get this working correctly?

Comment: Sorry to be a pedantic yobbo, but you don't use `o'clock` for non-hour boundaries. You don't even use it for military time. It's either one o'clock (in the afternoon) or thirteen hundred hours. 13:42 is simply spoken as thirteen-forty-two :-)

Comment: As a side note, I find it hilarious that this question usually gets upvoted the first business-day after a daylight saving time change :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The return value of `datetime('now')` is in UTC.

Try

```
datetime('now', 'localtime')
```

Comment: what about the date() function?

Comment: Since date() doesn't return time at all, I'd imagine that would also count as the wrong time.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' what happens to this date if the system date is wrong?

Comment: SQLite will correctly return the wrong date without error.

Answer (score 2):

datetime('now') will return in  <strike>GMT</strike>  UTC - which you probably should do then handle the conversion to your local timezone in the app.  If you keep it in UTC in the database, then convert it in your activities, your app will work correctly as the user moves around timezones

Comment: It's hasn't been GMT since Britain gave up the empire :-)